# Python: How to implement a static list in a class referencing all created items and an easy way to delete the items?

Tags: python, list, static, destructor

I have a class that stores all created references in a static list like this:

```
class A:
    _List = []

    def __init__(self):
        A._List.append(self)

    def __del__(self):
        A._List.remove(self)
```

Now if I do the following:

```
a = A()
del a
```

`a` is not deleted, since it is still referenced to in the list. But the reference would be destroyed if the destructor would be called. Is there a way to somehow force python to execute the `__del__` method anyway, so that it can get removed from the static list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `weakref.WeakValueDictionary` (or `weakref.WeakKeyDictionary`), it would automatcally remove any elements that do not exist anymore:

```
class A(object):
    _instances = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()
    _next_id = functools.partial(next, itertools.count())

    def __init__(self):
        self._instances[self._next_id()] = self
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`weakref.ref()`](http://docs.python.org/library/weakref.html#weakref.ref) to create weak references to store in the list. Use a callback to remove entries from the list when the object no longer exists.